# What is the proper way to handle login errors in Sybase, from a JDBC connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I access a Sybase database from a Java application. I can connect to it, execute statements, all of this works fine.

My issue is that I would like to handle correctly the cases when connection fails.

From my understanding, it can fail for the following reasons:

- Incorrect password
- Password expired
- Account is locked

So my question is: how can I properly handle these error cases, how can I recognize which one happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From several tests, I found out the different cases:

### Expired password

In this case, the database allows a connection, but a very limited one. The only thing you can call is the procedure to change password. The connection returned comes with a SQLWarning with the [errorcode 4022](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.39996_1250/html/svrtsg/svrtsg319.htm), and a description stating:

> The password has expired, but you are
> still allowed to log in. You must
> change your password before you can
> continue. If a login trigger is set,
> it will not be executed.

Thanks to the specific error code, it is possible to recognized the error, and propose to change the password in the client program.

---

### Invalid password and Locked account

There is no difference for both cases. When requesting a connection, it throws a SQLException which links to a SQLWarning as next exception, with the [error code 4002](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.39996_1250/html/svrtsg/svrtsg319.htm), and a very simple description:

> Login failed.

As such, there is not really a way to handle these cases specifically.

---

### Bonus case: password expiring soon

When a password will expire soon, the connection returned will contain a SQLWarning with the [code 4023](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.39996_1250/html/svrtsg/svrtsg319.htm), stating:

> Your password will expire in %s days.

This allows to show a warning in the client program, proposing the change the password already.

Answer (score 0):

Handle it like you would other messages from the database.  Catch the exception a log the message (this will help you identify the cause.  At the same time display a message to the user that either a database error occurred or that the database could not be accessed.